# ERROR Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefine

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can i fix this problem in my react native code the error says  "ERROR  Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.Check the render method of `TopNavigation`."

I tried restarting my app restarting my machine but this error didint gone can anyone can help me to fix this problem?

This is how I am exporting:

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../../assets/Logo.png';
import { icons1, logo2 } from '../Styles/styles';
import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import { Entypo } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

export default TopNavigation = ({ navigation, page }) => {

    return (
        <View style={page === 'home' ? styles.container : {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            width: '100%',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            zIndex: 100,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}>
            <Entypo name="camera" size={24} color="black" style={icons1}
                onPress={() => navigation.navigate('c')}
            />
            {
                page === 'home' ? <Image source={logo} style={logo2} /> :
                    <Image />
            }
         
            {
                page === 'profile' &&
                <Ionicons name="settings-sharp"
                    size={24}
                    color="black"
                    style={styles.icons11}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settings')}
                />
            }
        </View>

    )
}
```

And this is show I am using that component:
`import TopNavigation from '../../Components/TopNavigation';`

`<TopNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />`

My DependencieS:

```
"dependencies": {
"@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.11",
"@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.0.5",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.3",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.9",
"@shopify/flash-list": "^1.4.1",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.71.2",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
"react-native-screens": "^3.19.0",
"react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
},
```

```
import { StyleSheet, View, StatusBar } from 'react-native';
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import BottomNavigation from '../../Components/BottomNavigation';
import TopNavigation from '../../Components/TopNavigation';

export default function Home({ navigation }) {

    const [userdata, setUserdata] = useState(null);


    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
        .then((keys) => {
            keys.forEach((key) => {
                AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
                    .then((value) => {
                        console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        console.log(`Error retrieving data for key ${key}: ${error}`);
                    });
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(`Error retrieving keys: ${error}`);
        });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <StatusBar />
            <BottomNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
            <TopNavigation navigation={navigation} page={'home'} />
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: add code of TopNavigation to be more precise

Comment: @VickyAhuja Pls check again i updated

Comment: @VickyAhuja same issue again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is **issue in code of TopNavigation component.**

As I tried same code in codesandbox, **issues seems with Entypo component**.

**try to remove the usage of Entypo component and use another workaround instead Entypo.**

try below solution, hope it works for you.

ex.

```
import { StyleSheet, View, Image } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../../assets/Logo.png';
import { icons1, logo2 } from '../Styles/styles';
import { Ionicons } from 'react-native-vector-icons';
import { Entypo } from 'react-native-vector-icons';

export default TopNavigation = ({ navigation, page }) => {

    return (
        <View style={page === 'home' ? styles.container : {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            width: '100%',
            paddingVertical: 10,
            position: 'absolute',
            top: 0,
            zIndex: 100,
            backgroundColor: 'black',
        }}>
            {
                page === 'home' ? <Image source={logo} style={logo2} /> :
                    <Image />
            }
         
            {
                page === 'profile' &&
                <Ionicons name="settings-sharp"
                    size={24}
                    color="black"
                    style={styles.icons11}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('settings')}
                />
            }
        </View>

    )
}
```

Comment: same error coming again

Comment: attach image of code which using this TopNavigation component

Comment: i have provided in my code that how I am importing the component https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343737/error-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components?noredirect=1#comment132945467_75343737:~:text=And%20this%20is%20show%20I%20am%20using

Comment: I am asking for full file code so I can know how it is being executed

Comment: oh pls check my edited question i provided

Comment: can you try to comment the BottomNavigation component usage line

Comment: same error after commenting it

Comment: tried your code on codesandbox, found issue Entypo component, comment the usage of the Entypo component in TopNavigation

Comment: yep thats works! thank you for your answer can you edit your answer with it so that I can tick your  answer?

Comment: @Code check new answer